# Scala - using a list of ints as an index to populate a new data structure

Tags: list, scala, dictionary, indexing

I have a list of Objects (Items, in this case) which have category ids and properties (which itself is a list of custom types).

I am trying to def a function that takes a list of integers e.g. `List(101, 102, 102, 103, 104)` that correspond to the category ids for the Items and creates a list of tuples that include the category type (which is an Option) and each property type from a list of properties that go along with each category. So far I have the below, but I am getting an error that `value _2 is not a member of Product with Serializable`.

```
def idxToData(index: List[Int], items: Seq[Item]): List[(Option[Category], Property[_])] = {

  def getId(ic: Option[Category]): Int => {
   ic match {
     case Some(e) => e._id
     case None => 0
    }
  }

  index.flatMap(t => items.map(i => if(t == getId(i.category)){
    (i.category, i.properties.list.map(_.property).toList.sortWith(_._id < _._id))
  } else {
    None
  }.filter(_ != None )
  ))
   .map(x => x._2.map(d => (x._1, d)))
   .toList
}
```

I am not sure how it is assigning that type (I am assuming at that point that I should have a list of tuples that I am trying to map).

Overall, is there a better way in scala to achieve the desired result from taking in a list of indices and using that to access the specific items in a list where a tuple of two parts of each corresponding item would "replace" the index to create the new list structure?

Comment: That's a bit of a tangle there.  Any chance you can pull out some of the functionality into a local def (and then see if the problem persists)?  There are also other worrying aspects that the compiler would probably tell you about if it compiled (e.g. what about `case None`?).  And you can use `sortBy` as a shorthand if you just want to do the usual sort on something computed from the elements.  (`sortBy(_.foo)` is the same as `sortWith(_.foo < _.foo)`).

Comment: @RexKerr yeah, it is a bit of a tangle, I am still getting my legs with scala and fp. I at least pulled the match statement out to it's own local def and added a case for None to send back 0. It still seems to persist with the `Product of Serializable` - not sure why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should split your code, give names to things (add some vals and some defs), and when the compiler does not agree with you, write types, so that the compiler will tell you early where it disagrees (don't worry, we all did that when starting with FP)

Also, when posting such a question, you might want to give (relevant parts of) the interface of elements that are referenced but not defined. What are "is" (is that items?), Item, category, properties...., or simplify your code so that they do not appear.

Now, to the problem :

```
if(t == (i.category match { case Some(e) => e._id})){
   (i.category, i.properties.list.map(_.property).toList.sortWith(_._id < _._id))
} else {
  None
}
```

The first branch is the type `Tuple2`(Int, whatever) while the second branch is of the completely unrelated type `None`. Clearly, there is no common super type better than `AnyRef`, so that is the type of the if expression. Then the type of is.map (supposing `is` is some sort of `Seq`) will be `Seq`[AnyRef]. filter does not change the type, so still `Seq[AnyRef]`, and in the `map(x =>...)`, `x` is an `AnyRef` too, not a `Tuple2`, so it has no `_2`.

Of course, the list actually contains only tuples, because originally it had tuples and Nones and you have removed the Nones. But that was lost to the compiler when it typed that `AnyRef`. 
(as the compiler error message tells and as noted by Imm, the compiler finds a slightly more precise type than `AnyRef`, `Product with Serializable`; however, that will not do you any good, all of the useful typing information is still lost there).

To preserve the type, in general you should do something such as

```
if(....) {
   Some(stuff)
else
   None
```

That would have been typed Option[type of stuff], where type of stuff is your Pair.

However, there is something simpler with routine collect. 
It is a bit like match, except that it takes a partial function, and it discard elements for which the partial function is not defined.

So that would be

```
is.collect { case i if categoryId(i) == Some(t) => 
   (i.catetory, i.properties....)
}
```

supposing you have defined

```
def categoryId(item: Item): Option[Int] = item.category.map(._id)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
is.map(i => if(t == getId(i.category)){
  (i.category, i.properties.list.map(_.property).toList.sortWith(_._id < _._id))
} else {
  None
}
```

you get a `List[Product with Serializable]` (what you should probably get is a type error, but that could be a long digression), because that's the only supertype of `None` and `(Category, List[Property[_]])` or whatever that tuple type is. The compiler isn't smart enough to carry the union type through and figure out that when you `filter(_ != None)` anything left in the list must be the tuple.

Try to rephrase this part. E.g. you could do `is.filter(i => t == getId(i.category))` *first*, before the `map`, and then you wouldn't need to mess around with `None`s in your list.